# Prove $(\int_0^1f(x))^2>\int_0^1f^3(x)$

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that $\int_0^x f^3 \le \left(\int_0^x f\right)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34780/prove-that-int-0x-f3-le-left-int-0x-f-right2)

Assume $f(x)$ is derivable in[0,1],and when $x\in$(0,1), $0<f^{'}(x)<1,f(0)=0$

Prove

$(\int_0^1f(x))^2>\int_0^1f^3(x)$