# Integral inequality: $3\left(\int_0^1 g(x)^2 dx\right)^3 \geq \int_0^1 g(x)^8 dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integral-inequality

**Problem:** Suppose that $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function such that $0\leq g'(x)\leq 1$ for each $x\in[0,1]$ and $g(0)=0.$ Prove that $$3\left(\int_0^1 g(x)^2 dx\right)^3 \geq \int_0^1 g(x)^8 dx.$$

I tried with bounds like $g(x)^m\le m\int_0^x g(t)^{m-1}dt$ but that did not work out. Another small observation is that equality holds here for $g(x)=x,$ so we should give bounds that admit equality for this $g.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $\forall x \in [0,1]$,

$$3\left(\int_0^X g(x)^2 dx\right)^3 \geq \int_0^X g(x)^8 dx.$$

> Differentiate both sides. What do you get?

$ $

> Differentiate both sides. What do you get?

$ $

> Differentiate both sides. What do you get?

$ $

Now, do it in reverse.

---

If you really really want more hand holding:

> [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34780/prove-that-int-0x-f3-le-left-int-0x-f-right2?rq=1) is a more basic version of this problem. Adapt it.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks!

Comment: I had shown $g(x)^3 \leq 3\int_0^x g(t)^2 dt,$ but was stuck after that. Now it worked out.